# We are trying from Instagram importing Instagramy from python but it's not working

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-story

I want to scrape the data from Instagram different public and private accounts. But when I run the following code.

```
from instagramy import Instagram


# Connecting the profile
user = Instagram("ihtishamKhattak")

# printing the basic details like
# followers, following, bio
print(user.is_verified())
print(user.popularity())
print(user.get_biography())

# return list of dicts
posts = user.get_posts_details()

print('\n\nLikes', 'Comments')
for post in posts:
    likes = post["likes"]
    comments = post["comment"]
    print(likes,comments)
```

[image: import error]

Comment: The documentation (https://pypi.org/project/instagramy/) says to use `InstagramUser` instead:
`from instagramy import InstagramUser`   
`user = InstagramUser('ihtishamKhattak')`
`print(user.is_verified)`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the `instagramy` pypi [page](https://pypi.org/project/instagramy/).

There is no Instagram python module. Also make sure, that you have no script calles `instagramy.py`

Answer (score 0):

change your script to

```py
from instagramy import InstagramUser


# Connecting the profile
user = InstagramUser("ihtishamKhattak")
```

Beware that this might work only for few request if you do not provide a Session ID.